# Polynomial in finite field where all the elements of the field are roots

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields

Find a monic polynomial of degree n where n is a power of a prime p and every element of F_n is a root.

I attempted to solve this problem by using the fact that every element in a finite field can be thought of as a root of unity. So since 1-x^n is always zero for an nth root of unity, I thought that was the answer, but it’s wrong.

Comment: $x^{p^k}-x$. This works by Lagrange's theorem.

Comment: Why doesn’t 1-x^n work? Also, what is k?

Comment: @AlexWang : $n=p^k$. $X^n-1$ doesn't work because the multiplicative group of the field has order $n-1=p^k-1$ and not $n$.

Comment: $x=0$ is not a root of $1-x^n$. The non-zero elements have orders that are factors of _____?